# Convex quadratic program plus one non-convex term

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

How would you approach a standard convex quadratic program with convex constraints but one non-convex term? Say $|x|^{0.4}$.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x}{\text{minimize}} & \frac12 x^{T} Q x + g^T x + c^T \cdot \mbox{sign}(x) \cdot |x|^{0.4}\\ \text{subject to} & A x \leq b\end{array}$$

where $|\cdot|$ and $\mbox{sign}(\cdot)$ are applied element-wise. Is there any other way to solve the problem within convex framework? What's the best way to approximate if the dimensions are large?

This is similar to [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28035), but here there is a power term.

Comment: If the non-convex term is smooth then you can sometimes get away with incorporating its gradient into another run-of-the-mill algorithm. However, the results I'm familiar with usually prefer that the gradient satisfies some sort of Lipschitz condition. The gradient of your nonconvex function goes off to $+\infty$ at $0$, so that ain't gonna fly... You could *try* throwing an algorithm at it and see if it gives you something reasonable, but I don't know if there are many convergence guarantees. I'd advise hard-coding some maximal step sizes to make sure it doesn't go too haywire.

Comment: The product $\cdot$ in $\operatorname{sign}(x) \cdot |x|^{0.4}$ is hadamard product? In other words, $(\operatorname{sign}(x) \cdot |x|^{0.4})_i = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} x_i^{0.4} & \text{if}~x>0 \\ -x_i^{0.4} & \text{if}~x<0 \end{array}\right.$?

Comment: Yes, it`s a hadamard product.

Comment: Do you really need the $\text{sign}(x)$ term? I think it might be easier without it (but not sure).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answer is correct.

**(1) The projected gradient descent may work.**

Let's start with function $\varphi(x)$:
\begin{equation}
\varphi(x) = c^T \cdot \operatorname{sign}(x) \circ |x|^{0.4} = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \operatorname{sign}(x_i) {|x_i|}^{0.4}, \quad \forall  x \in \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation}
For convenience, we define
\begin{equation}
\varphi_i(x) = c_i \operatorname{sign}(x_i) {|x_i|}^{0.4}
\end{equation}
and thus $\varphi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(x)$.
Now we can compute the (sub)differential of $\varphi_i(\cdot)$ at $x$:
\begin{equation}
\partial \varphi_i(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
0.4c_i x_i^{-0.6} & \text{if}~x_i > 0, \\
(-\infty, + \infty) & \text{if}~x_i = 0, \\
-0.4c_i x_i^{-0.6} & \text{if}~x_i < 0.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
Let $\psi(x)$ be
\begin{equation}
\psi(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TQx+g^Tx+c^T \cdot \operatorname{sign}(x) \circ |x|^{0.4},
\end{equation}
and we can compute its gradient:
\begin{equation}
[\nabla \psi(x)]_i = [Qx]_i + g_i + c_i + \partial \varphi_i(x).
\end{equation}
In this sense, we can apply the projected gradient descent method.

**(2) We can applying the DC programming.**

We can easily find that
\begin{equation}
\phi_i(x) = c_i \operatorname{sign}(x_i) |x_i|^{0.4} = c_i \frac{x_i}{|x_i|}|x_i|^{0.4} = c_i x_i |x_i|^{-0.6}.
\end{equation}
Furthermore, we have
\begin{equation}
\varphi_i(x) = \frac{c_i}{2} \left[(x_i + |x_i|^{-0.6})^2 - (x_i^2 + x_i^{-1.2})\right].
\end{equation}
Let $$f_i(x) = (x_i + |x_i|^{-0.6})^2, \quad g_i(x) = (x_i^2 + x_i^{-1.2}),$$
and we can find that $f_i(x)$ and $g_i(x)$ are both convex function.
Thus $$\phi_i(x) = \frac{c_i}{2}(f_i(x) - g_i(x))$$ is a DC (difference of convex) function.
We can applying the DC programming to solve this problem.
For details, in iteration $\textit{k}$, we try to solve the following convex optimization subproblem:
\begin{equation}
x^{k+1} = \mathop{\arg\min}_x \left\{\frac{1}{2}x^TQx+g^Tx + \hat{\varphi}(x;x^k), \quad \text{s.t.} Ax \leq b\right\}.
\end{equation}
where $\hat{\varphi}(x;x^k)$ is the approximation of $\varphi(x)$ by linearizing the subtracted term at $x^k$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\hat{\varphi}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \hat{\varphi}_i(x), \quad \hat{\varphi}_i(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\frac{c_i}{2}\left[f_i(x) - g_i'(x)(x_i-x_i^k) \right] & \text{if}~c_i \ge 0, \\
-\frac{c_i}{2} \left[g_i(x) - f_i'(x)(x_i-x_i^k) \right] & \text{if}~c_i < 0.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
The subproblem can be solve by some convex optimization algorithm, e.g. projected gradient method, block coordinate descent, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the comment ! You sure that f(x) is convex ?

Comment: @Kreol, yes, you can compute the second-order differential of $f(x)$ to determine the convexity.

Comment: I did, but my cvxpy keeps complainig ((x + cp.abs(x) ** -0.6) ** 2).is_convex(). Maybe you know what could be the issue here ?

Comment: @Kreol, that is an interesting finding. It seems that there exists some error in is_convex() but I am not sure. I obverse that the function $f(x) = (x+|x|^{-0.6})^2$ is symmetric, and the result of ((x + x ** -0.6) ** 2).is_convex() is true when $x > 0$. However, the result of ((x + cp.abs(x) ** -0.6) ** 2).is_convex() is False when $x < 0$.

Comment: There is a jump in 0 and the function is not symmetric

Comment: @Kreol The discontinued point at $0$ is not a serious problem. But I am confused that why function $f(\cdot)$ is not symmetric?

Comment: Sorry why do you think discontinuity is not a problem ? I believe that`s what causes the function to be non-convex. Please explain. Also, would it help if we drop the sign(x) ? so just c^T |x|^0.4